# Is there a simple way to implement word wrap for strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, math

I have a simple control that shows a piece of text where the contents, size, position, etc are controlled via Python. Is there a way to calculate an accurate height for the control given a fixed width?

Right now I am doing:

```
a = total_number_of_characters_in_string
b = max_number_of_characters_in_a_line
h = a/b
```

But the problem is not every line is filled to the max, and there are also new line characters.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Check out the [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting.

Comment: If you're using a variable width font, the solution is almost certainly going to be more complicated than if you're using a fixed width font. That is, there's probably not any easier way to find out the width of a variable-width font text than just laying it out and asking the GUI how long it is.